# Java import /lib files

Tags: java, import, javac, lib

I have a project with globally this architecture:

rtreeProject
--com
----geospatial
------Point.java
------Rectangle.java
--lib
----gnu
------trove
----org
------slf4j

How can I import classes from my *lib* folder into the *Rectangle.java* file from example?

I'm compiling manually using *javac*.

Thanks

Comment: People who put a -1, can you please give me a clue. A critic without feedback makes no progress. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ***javac -classpath ...*** command was ok (see ***man javac***)
The library documentation was obsolete so ma package names were not found
A ***jar tf*** on the jarfile revealed the new packages names
Sorry for pollution
Best